# Blocking windows switching via touchpad

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

Every time I scroll through a webpage, the windows switcher applications shows up.

I have realized that the behaviour happens when I do horizontal move with my fingers instead of a vertical but it is too sensitive so it happens all the time.

How can I disable this action?

I would like to only scroll with my touchpad on the browser, and use only <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch apps.

Answer (score 2):

You have to disable horizontal scrolling.

Using **dconf Editor**:

1. open dconf Editor through the Dash;
2. go to **org > gnome > settings-daemon > peripherals > touchpad**;
3. check **horiz-scroll-enabled**, as you see in the screenshot.

[image: Enable horizontal scrolling]

If you do not have dconf editor, you can install it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Comment: What does that have to do with window switching?

Comment: I don't have an option `touchpad`, but have a touchpad...:/